# Hystrix method deprecated

Tags: netflix, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using hystrix api version 1.5.4.  I am seeing that the method     `withExecutionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds` is deprecated. What is the alternate method instead?

```
    public HystrixHelloCommand(String message) {
    super(HystrixCommand.Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("MyGroup")).andCommandPropertiesDefaults(
     HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
    .withCircuitBreakerEnabled(true).withExecutionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds(2000)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Doc](https://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/deprecated-list.html) it is replaced by `withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds` and this is what it says:

> com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommandProperties.Setter.withExecutionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds(int)
>   As of 1.4.0, replaced with
>   HystrixCommandProperties.Setter.withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(int).
>   Timeouts are no longer applied only to thread-isolated commands, so a
>   thread-specific name is misleading